# Not able to restore a backup to SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms, sql-server-2019

I am trying to a restore a SQL Server from a .bak file and always get the same error :

> The database was backed up on a server running version 15.00.2000.
> That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
> version 15.00.2000.

I have already seen the issue in Stackoverflow but I'm struggling because the versions here are the same ..

I am using SSMS and I already tried restoring to a SQL Server 2017, to the latest Cumulative update of SQL Server 2019 and to the first SP of SQL Server 2019. Wondering if I am missing something (configuration, code, ..) in SSMS to make it work.

Comment: Possibly related: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/01/03/sql-server-sql-azure-managed-instance-restore-error-the-database-was-backed-up-on-a-server-running-version-15-00-2000/ Are you using Azure Managed Instances?

Comment: Yeah, if backup was on Managed Instance, it cannot be restored to on-prem. BACKPAC is what is supported going from MI to on-prem.

Comment: You are correct that you cannot restore from Managed Instance to an on-prem version, but I think MI's still report their version as 12.0.20000; although they support just about every 2019 feature.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring it on SQL MI rather than Azure SQL DB or SQL Server worked perfectly